# Drupal 7 Node inside of node in a form

Tags: drupal

I am trying to do something like this:

- Project: Name, Due Date

  - Milestone: Due Date, Project

    - Task: Milestone, Title, Priority...etc

Is it possible to create a project with milestones and tasks all in one form and create all the nodes at once?

Answer (score 0):

in this case drupal work with this as 1 node... you can create one node with multiple form..

use CCK with [field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)  to group your node forms... you can create

Group for milestone form

Group for Task form

**ALL** of this is regarded as   one node.. but i don't think u can insert more than one node in the same form

Comment: This kind of works, but the problem is I would need to either treat the form as a collection of nodes or just 1 node. For example create an entire project, milestones, and tasks all at once, or just create a task.

Comment: In drupal you cant create multiple nodes in the same time... but you can use node reference field type ... see this  http://drupal.org/node/289738  and this  http://pras.net.np/blogs/guide-cck-nodereference